# Check if an object is of the same type as the passed one

Tags: java

I have class A and two classes B and C which extend A. I have an array list which contains multiple instances of all of these classes. Can I have a method which takes in an object and returns all objects in the array list which is of the same type as the one given to the method and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: `instanceOf()` usually lets you check which type something is

Comment: Do you have any code to post to show what you have tried?

Comment: I know about instanceof but I don't know in beforehand what type I am looking for and I can't seem to find a way to pass that through the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - you'd use `getClass()` to find the execution-time type:

```
private final List<A> allKnownValues = ...;

List<A> getAllValuesOfTheSameType(A sample) {
    ArrayList<A> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (A candidate : allKnownValues) {
        if (candidate.getClass() == sample.getClass()) {
            results.add(candidate);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

If you want to include *subtypes*, you could use:

```
if (sample.getClass().isInstance(candidate))
```

Comment: Thank you Jon this seems to fit my needs

Answer (score 0):

Although it's already answered, I had started creating an example, as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I'll just drop this here:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TypeFilterTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2.0f);
        list.add(3.0);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5.0f);
        list.add(6.0);
        list.add("seven");
        list.add(null);

        System.out.println("Integers    : "+findSameType(list, Integer.class));
        System.out.println("Floats      : "+findSameType(list, Float.class));
        System.out.println("Doubles     : "+findSameType(list, Double.class));

        System.out.println("Comparables : "+findSubType(list, Comparable.class));

    }

    private static <T> List<T> findSameType(List<? super T> list, Class<T> type)
    {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            Object element = list.get(i);
            if (element != null && element.getClass().equals(type))
            {
                result.add(type.cast(element));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static <T> List<T> findSubType(List<? super T> list, Class<T> type)
    {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            Object element = list.get(i);
            if (type.isInstance(element))
            {
                result.add(type.cast(element));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have that object somewhere to point to your list `List<A> yourOriginalList`

If you are using Java 8 you can write a reusable filter method not just for B or C elements but for anything you want to compare. This is using the new lamba expressions introduced in Java 8.

```
public List<A> getFilteredList(Predicate<A> predicate){
        List<A> filteredList = new ArrayList<A>();
        for(A value : yourOriginalList){
            if(predicate.test(value)){
                filteredList.add(value);
            }
        }
        return filteredList;
    }
```

To filter for B objects, use :

```
List<A> filteredListOfB = getFilteredList((value) -> value instanceof B);
```

To filter for C objects, use :

```
List<A> filteredListOfC = getFilteredList((value) -> value instanceof C);
```

As you can seee you can write anything you want to test in the parameter of `getFilteredList`

(not tested for syntax error, but the idea is here)